# gdb doesn't show the name of the function call

Tags: debugging, gdb, msys

gdb in msys, doesn't show the name of the function call. Next to the address of the function call I have normaly the name of the function like . Why it's not the case with this exe and how can I fix it? [gdb console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlsT1.png)

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it's not the case with this exe

Because GDB doesn't know what function address `0x4023d0` corresponds to.

> how can I fix it?

Depending on what code resides at address `0x4023d0`, and *why* GDB doesn't have a name associated with it, this may or may not be fixable. But there is not enough info for me to even begin guessing what code might be there.